# How to jump between functions and main() in C programming

Tags: c, function

How can I go back to the main function from another sub function?
in C programming

in main() the user is asked whether he want games or calculator.
if he chooses games for example, he will be going to the function games
when he is in games function he can choose which game he wants or going back to
the main menu which shows games and calculator.

eg:

```
//prototypes 
function one
function sub_one

main() {

select the function :
games:1
calculator:2 
go to ?(function games)?: .... 
}

//////////////////////////// 
function games { 

select the game :     
snake:1
painter:2
want to go back? yes? main()  
}

//////////////////////////// 
function snake {
  a+b .. get my work done here and i wanna goo back to games()
  want to go back? yes? function games()  
}
```

I succeeded to go back to previous functions except from the one which is pointed to in main().

I tried to define a global var and use it in a while loop inside main() in order to change
it from any function to be able to go back from any part of my code.

It seems pretty easy but I have lost my patience because I spent all my day trying 
to do this thing and that's why I am seeking a little hint from you.

Thank you so much.

Comment: in c programming. I  wish I could post the whole code but it is hundrads of lines. this is just a conceptional question seeking a conceptional answer not complete code.

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote this :) I really don't understand :) Perhaps you should explain with totally other words what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry guys. I don't regret my mistake by not offering any detail. I hope it is clear now.. appreciate it!

Comment: @salvatore, we all had to start learning languages from scratch once, and a program sketch in pseudo-code is an excellent way to convey the intention. I found it far more enlightening than the textual description, anyway.

Comment: I'm actually grateful that you didn't post your hundreds of lines of code. Be sure to check the following website before posting any code to StackOverflow: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Yes well I was tempted :) but I didn't :) I'm glad however that faisal founds his answer and that understood what was missing. Writing pseudocode is not simple but there is a formal way to do that too.

Comment: My formal method for writing pseudocode involves a cigar and a glass of Scotch.

Comment: Guys the answer is much much easier than I imagined.. just I called main() in that function and even if you were in the function number 5443524, you can go back easily. But in case you make some numeric conditions or global vars. just assign them to zeros as you are starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you return to the `main` function depends upon how you declared your other functions:

- if you declare the function `void function (...)`, then you can simply `return` at any point, or allow control to run off the end of the function -- the compiler will automatically return to the calling function
- if you declare the function to return a value `int function(...)` or `char * function(...)` then you must `return foo;` from your functions -- and `foo`'s type must match the return type of the function. You cannot simply allow control to run off the end of the function.

Some examples:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SNAKE 1
#define PAINTER 2

void play_snake() {
    /* play the snake game */
    return;
}

void play_painter() {
    /* sistine chapel time */
    return;
}

int prompt_for_choice() {
    char choice[10];
    puts("Please make a choice");
    puts("");
    puts("1 play snake");
    puts("2 play painter");
    fgets(choice, sizeof(choice), stdin);
    return strtol(choice, NULL, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int choice;

    choice = prompt_for_choice();

    if (choice == SNAKE) {
        play_snake();
    } else if (choice == PAINTER) {
        play_painter();
    } else {
        printf("internal error, invalid choice %d\n", choice);
        exit(1);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Note that there is nothing special about `main`. It is just another function.

I strongly recommend getting a good book about C. My favorite "first book" is [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). Be sure to get the second edition, as the first edition describes an earlier version of the language. (The first edition might still be fun reading, but does not accurately represent the C language as it is used today.)

Comment: Some notes: (1) I would prefer `switch` to cascaded `if` statements in a "real program", but C's `switch` has enough caveats that I don't think it's a great introduction to C. (2) I would prefer arrays of {string, function pointer} to the hard-coded menus, but again, function pointers are a bit steep for someone first learning C. Ask for elaboration if you're curious.

Answer (score 4):

You can get back to the main function by returning from the function most recently called by  `main()`. Note that you don't *call* `main()`, you simply return from your function to main. After the last statement of a function is executed, the next statement is the next one in the function that called it.

I think you actually want to control which function gets executed using some a state variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

enum {ff, gg, hh} state = ff;
void f();
void g();
void h();

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case ff:
                f();
            break;
            case gg:
                g();
            break;
            case hh:
                h();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void f()
{
    printf("f()\n");
    state = hh;
}

void g()
{
    printf("g()\n");
    exit(0);
}

void h()
{
    printf("h()\n");
    state = gg;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./foo 
f()
h()
g()
```

More cleanly, you could switch from a global to a local state variable by returning the new state at the end of the `f()`, `g()` and `h()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, just call a menu function that call all sub menus and when in the sub-menu, you can call back the menu function which lies in the main function. Also a newbie but hope this helps

```
#include<stdio.h>
int menu();
int games();
int calculator();

int main(){//main function starts
  menu();
  return 0;
}
int menu(){
  int choice;
  printf("Select Function\n");
  printf("1. Games\n");
  printf("2. Calculator\n");
  printf("3. Exit\n");

  scanf("%d",&choice);
  switch(choice){
    case 1:
    games();
    break;
    case 2:
    calculator();
    break;
    case 3:
    return 1;
    break;
    default:
    printf("invalid Choice\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
int games(){
  int choice2;
  printf("Select Game\n");
  printf("1. Snake\n");
  printf("2. Painter\n");
  printf("3. Go back to main Menu\n");
  scanf("%d",&choice2);
  switch(choice2){
    case 1:
    printf("Call function for Snake\n");
    ;break;
    case 2:
    printf("Call function for Painter\n");
    break;
    case 3:
    menu();
    default:
    printf("invalid Choice\n");
  }
return 0;
}
int calculator(){
  //code goes here
}
```